# Tomato plant drooping

Tags: tomatoes

I am having lots of difficulty with my tomato plant. It will look very health in the morning and after a few hours, start to droop completely. I am using a self watering pot and keep it filled. I thought I might be under watering and started watering more which just didn't make a difference. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add a photo please, showing the plant and its pot? Are you growing this indoors or outside?

Comment: Did you recently transplant/repot it?

Comment: Are the roots deep enough to get to the water?

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple issues with potted plants in general.

If the pot is too small or it gets too hot there or if the soil in the pot is too compacted and the water just goes around and comes out the bottom and it doesn't actually get to the roots.  There can be other issues too like the plant doesn't have a good root system for some reason and so it cannot absorb enough moisture during the hottest part of the day.  And even more fun could be disease problems.

So to provide a better answer it would help for us to know what kind of conditions, how big the plant is, where you are at, if you've repotted it, how much it gets watered, etc.

Remember the more details you give in your question the easier it is for people to answer.  :)

Comment: flowerbug makes a great point about the soil. If you used a soilless mix heavy in peat and it completely dried out, it may not be possible to completely re-wet it again. This would cause water to simply move down the sides of the pot as flowerbug notes. So, it could look like you're giving your plant plenty of water when it's really not getting much water at all.

Comment: it is possible to get it wet again, but it may need to be soaked for a while.  a self-watering pot should imply that it hasn't dried out completely, but are you sure that the water level in the base is actually getting up to the soil in the pot?